Helm install using a local compressed k8s-dashboard.tgz file. Can see the image with crictl command, but cannot resolve an "ImagePullBackOff" Err
I am having trouble installing Kubernetes-Dashboard onto my 4-node (1 Control Node, 3 Worker Node) cluster. I have been tasked to install RHEL 8 and RKE2 onto 4 servers that need to be available for a project in the next few weeks. the cluster contains two Dell R730 and two R620. My version of RKE2 is v1.27.10, Helm version is v3.13.3.
This cluster is also housed on an air-gapped network so I downloaded kubernetes/dashboard:latest as a kuberetes-dashboard-1-6-2.tgz and copied over to a NAS location on the local network. I then ran the following commands to install locally
kubectl create namespace kubernetes-dashboard
helm install kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard-1-6-2.tgz --create-namespace
After install, I am able to see Image Name "docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard" in my list of images
crictl images
When I run kubectl get pods -n kubernetes-dashboard all of the 5 associated pods have a status of ImagePullBackOff. I have added the mirror docker.io to my registries file as well. I tried to troubleshoot this by using the following command kubectl describe pod on any of the kubernetes-dashboard pods that are in this error state. The best I can tell where this error may be happening is after pulling image "docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard-api:1.7.0". The event following that step results in **Back-off pulling image "docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard-api:1.7.0".
Thanks for any insight into this issue.
